# Sequelize find all where currentUserEditor is not null

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How i find all from table where currentUserEditor !== null ?

I need to check if currentUserEditor and if it null other user can edit things but if there is a user that not null other user can edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use something like the next code and read this [doc](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#operators)

```
   const Op = require('sequelize').Op;

    Model.findAll({
      where: {
         currentUserEditor: {[Op.ne]: null}
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Other way is:

```
 const Op = require('sequelize').Op;

    Model.findAll({
      where: {
         currentUserEditor: {[Op.not]: null}
      }
    })
```

Because it generate a query similar with this:

```
SELECT * FROM "Model" AS "Model" WHERE "Model"."currentUserEditor" IS NOT NULL
```